# How to get Laravel Collection from Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get all results from two tables `akcii`, `feeds` and after search throw them (now query just returns all records without any conditions for search), here is the query (mysql):

```
DB::query('SELECT id, title, text FROM (
        SELECT id, title, text FROM `akcii` UNION ALL
        SELECT id, title, body FROM `feeds`
    ) temp_table
        ORDER BY `id` desc
        LIMIT 0, 10')
```

Results are exacly that I need but after I can't convert it Collection?
If I call `->get()` method I'm getting an error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select *)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In phpmyadmin this query return records well.

Comment: I'm using Mysql 5.5.41

Answer (score 2):

**DB::query()** method does not get any arguments, so the query you pass there is simply ignored. You're calling **get()** on an empty builder, which does not know what table to run the query on. Generated query is just **SELECT ***, hence the SQL error.

If you want that to work, you should call **DB::select()** method, e.g.:

```
$results = DB::select($your_query);
```

Still, what you'll get is an **array**, not a **Collection** object. If you want to make a collection out of it, do the following:

```
$collection = new Collection($results);
```

Comment: Can you show us the API documentation where you see that DB::query() takes no arguments?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L257

Comment: Connection is the class behind DB facade

Comment: Thanks, works, but now, cant use `paginate()` method.

Comment: You can't have Eloquent do the pagination on database level if you're using a raw query. Query needs to be built using query builder so that Eloquent knows how to apply pagination criteria.

Comment: Db::select($your_query)->paginate(5)->getCollection(); i believe it should do it

Comment: It won't, DB::Select() returns an array

Comment: What you could do is fetch all the rows from the database and paginate it programatically using Laravel's paginators - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator